# How to identify the parser configured for a given FULLTEXT index in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Given the following table definition,

```
CREATE TABLE `users_3` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `forename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
  FULLTEXT KEY `users_full_text` (`forename`,`surname`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */  
)
```

I can get information about the index doing:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM users
```

```
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| users | 1          | users_full_text | 1            | forename    | NULL      | 4444        | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   | YES     | NULL          |         |            |
| users | 1          | users_full_text | 2            | surname     | NULL      | 4444        | NULL     | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   | YES     | NULL          |         |            |
```

I see no mention of the option `WITH PARSER ngram`. Is there any way I can get this information?

I can find this in `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` but the returning value of this is not usable because I need to use this programatically.

Given an existing FULLTEXT index named users_full_text, how can I programatically find the PARSER that such an index is set up with?

I am using Mysql 8.1.0.

Comment: There's a feature request filed in 2017 for exactly this kind of metadata. So far, there is no solution. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87974